# Logging and monitoring in PySpark & Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

My understanding is that PySpark code is evaluated when Spark is building the DAG/query plan, not when the code is being executed. This means that adding logging messages in between e.g. `spark.sql` statements won't have the same effect as one might expect in a sequential, non-distributed runtime

I know that Spark provides its own log4j logs that Python can hook into, but the messages emitted from these tend to be a bit lower level than I would like. Ideally I would like my logging messages to map to the logic in my code, and not lower level Spark operations

I've read several discussions about logging in the Spark world, but not many posts specific to PySpark, and none documenting best practices or what folks tend to do "in the wild". I suppose this is partly because the PySpark documentation isn't very opinionated and doesn't provide recommendations on this front.

Concretely, these are my questions:

1. Spark doesn't provide any recommendations or guidance for structuring logging code. What about Databricks? Does the Databricks platform suggest any patterns or expose any APIs to make this process less painful? What about when delta live tables are involved, since that is a separate runtime altogether?
2. In the broader Spark world, are there any patterns for monitoring jobs and providing logging messages that are useful and meaningful for debugging/tracing, but don't incur extreme performance costs?

For example, for a simple batch job in a sequential, non-distributed environment, I might have logic like

```py
logging.info("Querying database for sales data")
sales_data, n_records = query(my_expensive_query)
logging.info(f"Finished querying database for sales data, query returned {n_records}")
```

But given what I wrote above, the two logging statements would both be run immediately on the start of the run when PySpark builds its evaluation plan, which is not what one would expect (namely, immediately before and immediately after the query). What would be the equivalent in "idiomatic" pyspark?